# How to get list of domains pointed in unique IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain, ip, domain-name

I want to know this is possible that i can get whole domains list which is pointed in unique (same) ip address

example:

```
i have ip 
000.000.00.00
now i want to get whole ip list which is pointed in this server ip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible.

Ok, not impossible, but to do it, you would need to brute-force iterate through the entire DNS name space. Needless to say, this would be **very** expensive and **very** time consuming.

Additionally, DNS is non-deterministic. Due to round-robin and other load balancing methods, just because you query a record once does not mean you have received the only possible answer for that query. So even if you iterated through the entire DNS name space once, you **still** would not have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: i like your before answer no need to edit it (this is impossible) by the way thanks for your help, i have understand good suggestion@EEAA